# How to keep User's Unlock status updated in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and using ASP.NET Identity to manage users (Lockout/Unlock statuses).

When I'm querying users in the database, I want to show the user's Lock/Unlock status **updated**. How can I achieve that?

Consider this scenario: John Doe is trying to sign in and he is locked out after 3 wrong password attempts; his `LockoutEndDate` column set to **3 hours later**.

In the meantime, a system administrator queries the users and he want to see locked users, as expected, `John Doe` is on that list.

John Doe didn't return to the system for 5 hours, but must be shown as an unlocked user because the lock time was 3 hours.

The solution I'm thinking about is to executing a script job in SQL Server Agent to keep the lock/unlock status updated. I'm seeking for a better approach.

Users have been locked out by WrongPasswordAttemptsReached or manually by administrators either and we want to distinguish this situation in reports.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even need to "keep the unlock status" up to date?? Just base your decision on the `LockoutEndDate`:

- if the `LockoutEndDate` is NULL --> no lockout has ever been set, user is **active**
- if the `LockoutEndDate` is set and has not yet expired (now() <= `LockoutEndDate`) --> user is **locked**
- if the `LockoutEndDate` is set, but it **has expired** (now() > `LockoutEndDate`) --> user is **active** again

No need for any flags and updating those with a SQL Server Agent job.....

Comment: But sometimes, administrators may lockout users (some reasons) and we want to distinguish between WrongPasswordAttemptsFailed and LockedByAdmin. How can I do that with your suggestion?

Comment: @TheMahd: in that case, you might need an additional flag/date column `LockedByAdmin` - not sure what your actual requirements for that are, so I cannot be very specific here.....